# UIDocumentInteractionController does not preview zip files

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad, uidocumentinteraction

I use a `UIDocumentInteractionController` to display a preview of almost all document types in my app. Until iOS 5.1, zip files were handled by `UIDocumentInteractionController` - it did not preview the content but showed a placeholder. However, `UIDocumentInteractionController` no longer shows a preview at all. Any advice on getting `UIDocumentInteractionController` to preview a zip file would be appreciated please.

Comment: It will not diaplay a preview, but you can open it with other applications: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10929172/uidocumentinteractioncontroller-crashes-without-any-log-message-why