# Compiler error "use of undeclared identifier" when I remove my @synthesize statements

Tags: objective-c, compiler-errors, clang, synthesize, declared-property

With the latest LLVM build, the requirement for synthesizing properties has been removed.

Therefore I was able to remove all my `@synthesize` statements except for the ones for `NSFetchedResultsController`.  Does anyone know why the compiler is warning me when I remove the `@synthesize fetchedResultsController;` line?

Error:

> Use of undeclared identifier "fetchedResultsController", did you mean _fetchedResultsController?

This is my code:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;

@synthesize fetchedResultsController;

- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {
    if (fetchedResultsController) {
        return fetchedResultsController;
    }

    if (!self.managedObjectContext) {
        self.managedObjectContext = [(MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];
    }

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Session" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    [fetchRequest setPredicate: self.predicate];

    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"timeStamp" ascending:NO];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];

    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    fetchedResultsController= [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
    fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    return fetchedResultsController;
}
```

Comment: might help if you shared the exact warning.

Comment: Thanks. By the way, that is not a warning - that is an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you don't put an `@synthesize` in your code, the instance variable created to back the property is named `_propertyName`. You are referring to the instance variable `fetchedResultsController` which no longer exists after you remove the `@synthesize`. Instead, change all references to `fetchedResultsController` to `_fetchedResultsController`.

Answer (score 1):

Because the default synthesized variable is `_fetchedResultsController` not `fetchedResultsController`

Answer (score 1):

The property `fetchedResultsController` is automatically synthesized to `_fetchedResultsController`, and this happens for every synthesized variable.

You should synthesize it explicitly to change its name.